# Is it safe to delete the Skype entry in PATH?

Tags: windows, skype, path

Skype installer adds this directory to the PATH environment variable:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone
```

This is frustrating, my PATH is already cluttered enough. So, I tried removing this entry, and Skype seems to start fine.

The directory contains these files:

```
Skype.exe
RtmCodecs.dll
RtmMediaManager.dll
RtmPal.dll
RtmPltfm.dll
SkypeResources.dll
Login.cab
```

Questions:

- Is it okay to remove this directory from the PATH? Will I be missing some (so-called) features?
- What is the intended purpose of this PATH addition?

Comment: Any application that integrates with Skype likely will fail.  Skype works because it uses its own location to determine the path to those files.

Comment: Could you provide examples of such applications?

Comment: That entirely depends on your individual setup.  I personally don't enable that functionality on my system.

Comment: I get lots of spam from my antimalware when I have that path variable still up(like every second). I generally delete it due to that and it works just fine without it at least for what I use it for(just skype convos and chatting).

Comment: Thanks though :) Your antimalware would need to be improved to support skype, it's not an uncommon software. Maybe you could contact them.